# puzzles of probabilities

Tags: probability, puzzle

> A grandmother is cleaning out her garage and finds 6 items that she no longer wants to store.  She has two charities that she likes to donate to, so she is going to put the 6 items into two boxes.  She wants to give at least one item to each charity. She does not care which charity gets which items, so the boxes are not labeled.
>
> How many different ways are there for her to place the 6 items into 2 unlabeled boxes?

For example {{$1,2,3,4$},{$5,6$}} is one way and {{$1,2,4,5$},{$3,6$}} is another.

But   {{$1,2,3,4,6$},{$5$}} is the same as   {{$5$},{$1,2,3,4,6$}}?
The choices are 
31
11
36
30
12
15

Answer (score 2):

In the first box you have to put either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 items. Remaining items should go into the second box.

Number of ways to pick elements for the first box is therefore:

$$\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{5}=2^6-\binom{6}{0}-\binom{6}{6}=62\tag{1}$$

But boxes are unlabeled: if you denote the set in the first box with $A$ and in the second box with $B$, arrangements (A,B) and (B,A) are equivalent. In other words, each distinct combination is counted twice in (1). So the result is (1) divided by 2, which is 31.

Comment: @OsamaNatouf Your choices are 31, 11, 36, 30, 12, 15 and my answer is 31. So what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I apologize for that.

Comment: @No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 2):

One box will contain item $6$. Together with $6$ there can be any subset of $[5]:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ other than $[5]$ itself. There are $2^5-1=31$ such subsets; and this is the answer to your question.